# Best way to distinguish links for internal action and ajax request?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, hyperlink, action

Because [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21231/pattern-for-webapp-action-link-using-no-hash-fragment) topic turn out to interdisciplinary (but still is about user experience) I'm curiuos what think about this an javacript developers.

My site handling `a` tags with `href` starting with `#` as ajax request. If request was successfully then it's change document hash to appropiate. Now I want to implement action links that call internal js function like going to site top, but I don't want `javascript:myAction()` reference, because most browsers is showing hint with referencing url when you're over the link. Probably I can use and successfully handle own url schema like `action:myAction`, but it's not enough solution - user was still hinted about magic url. Another option is using custom attribute like `action="myAction"` with `href` as custom string e.g. `href="Go to top"`, but what with browsers compatibility? Last solution is to using a `span` styled as link to perfom action - user is not hinted about any url, but this is a part of link functionality what suggest that perform an action (going to url default).

What is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
if(window.addEventListener)//Chrome, Firefox and Safari
    document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click',function(e){
        var e = e || event;
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = destiny;
    });
else//IE and Opera
    document.getElementById('myLink').attachEvent('onclick',function(e){
        var e = e || event;
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = destiny;
    });
</script>
<a href="#" id="myLink">Link</a>
```

Comment: I know how to implement. I ask what solution is better from user perspective. One acts as regular link, second not. If I can I give you -1, because this is not what I asking for. I dont understood why you write any code...

Comment: I guess this way is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

You should make your links work first [*without* JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Then you don't have to worry about someone clicking `<a href='/customers'>Customers!</a>`. It works nicely and is accessible. Once you've reached this point you put the JavaScript on top to enhance the user experience. How you hook all of these up is up to you - say you want to handle deletes in a generic way, you might have links that look like this:

```
<a href='/customers/2' class='delete'>Delete customer</a>

<a href='/customers/2' data-action='delete'>Delete customer</a>
```

Or if it's specific per link, you set the id and wire it up that way:

```
<a href='/customers/2' id='delete'>Delete customer</a>
```

All of this wiring up should be done in an external JavaScript file.

Comment: I'm not usign server-related links because my webapp has only one html file called index (currently it's php). All data request has done by catching links on `a` tag with `href` starting with hash and is translated and handled by client-side ajax engine. This is strictly JS application. When you hover a link then your browser's built-in action inform you about it's url. All I want is to nice solution to use no-request internal-js-action links with user-friendly browser built-in hint. Or without if there is no other way.Ah

Comment: Ah - of course handling of links with href-first-hash must stay as is. Code to an event handling is not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by first writing everything in a way users without JS can use it, like

```
<a href="#" title="Go to the top of the page">Go to top</a>
```

Then I would take JS to enhance it immediatly after the DOM is loaded. First by adding the `onclick` event, then removing the `href`, to avoid any link hint (any other content than links probably not pass any validator) and finally a new style attribute that the cursor becomes a pointer on hover.

It is part of the very useful [programmatic progressive enhancement structure](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/). This way I get valid and compatible code as well as a comfortable behaviour.